# refresh a page without visiting it

Tags: javascript, php

I created a script to send email every 30 days to my users, however, to start it I have to visit the page with my script inside. Is there a way to start a php script without visiting that page? So that the mechanism is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you could use [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: [If you're going to paste a link (as per http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35677283/1) (*which I might add that link-only answers are highly discouraged* http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/), make it an English one. Not everyone, including myself understands what looks to be German.